# Different behaviour of Newtonsoft.Json on .NET 5 / Core and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-5

The following program results in different outcomes when run on .NET 5 (or .NET Core) and .NET Framework.

Why is the behaviour different? I'm not after the solution to the deserialisation problem; my goal here is to understand what happens.

```cs
class Versioned 
{
    public Version V {get; set;} = new Version(1,0);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Serialised with version Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1
    var json = "{\"V\":{\"Major\":2,\"Minor\":0,\"Build\":-1,\"Revision\":-1,\"MajorRevision\":-1,\"MinorRevision\":-1}}";

    Console.WriteLine($".NET: {System.Environment.Version}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Json.NET: {System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert))}");

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    
    try 
    {
        var b = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Versioned>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(b.V);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message); }
}
```

On .NET 5: the output is (formatted for readability):

```
.NET: 5.0.1
Json.NET: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
{
    "V": {
        "Major": 2,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Build": -1,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
    }
}
```

With this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Version' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON string value or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'V.Major', line 1, position 14.

On .NET Framework 4.6.2 the output is:

```
.NET: 4.0.30319.42000
Json.NET: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
{
    "V": {
        "Major": 2,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Build": -1,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
    }
}
1.0
```

---

Additionally, with NO default value the behaviour on .NET 4.6.2 is different again.

```
class Versioned
{
    public Version V { get; set; }// = new Version(1, 0);
}
```

On .NET 5.0 the output is the same:

```
(...)
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Version' because...
```

On .NET Framework 4.6.2 the output now is:

```
(...)
Version's parameters must be greater than or equal to zero.
Parameter name: build
```

As far as I know, the `System.Version` class has not changed (on the outside) between these .NET versions in a way that should play a part here (I know only of the `ISpanFormattable` difference). I had a peek at the source ([.NET Core version](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Version.cs)  and [.NET Framework 4.8 version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs,0c15515dfe051d35)) but I cannot see anything that would explain the different behaviours.

Comment: What happens if you update `Newtonsoft.Json` from 11 version to the latest one?

Comment: The behavior with the latest version of Json.NET (12.0.3) is the same as for v11.

Comment: I'm not sure how that ever worked... Based on the fact that the .NET Framework version didn't throw, I'm assuming it used reflection to find those backing fields, and did some fancy mapping to remove the leading `_`. Note that those backing fields have changed to `readonly` in .NET 5: that won't necesarily stop reflection, but perhaps it's enough to make json.net give up. Can you try on .NET 5 with your own Version class, which has non-readonly backing fields?

Comment: Interestingly, a custom version of `Version` with `readonly` fields also works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tPP3rv . I removed the `ToString` stuff, but that *shouldn't* affect anything.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Json.NET got a new [`VersionConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_VersionConverter.htm) in .NET Core 2.2, which knows how to properly serialize and deserialize `Version` instances. This automatically gets picked up and used when you're using .NET Core 2.2+.

Using `VersionConverter`, Json.NET wants to serialize your `Version` objects to strings like `"1.0"`, rather than to JSON objects. If you create the `json` string in your post by serializing a new instance of `Versioned` on .NET Core 2.2+:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Versioned());
```

You'll see that it returns e.g. `{"V":"1.0"}`.

Likewise, `VersionConverter` only knows how to read version strings such as `"1.0"`, and doesn't know what to do with an object containing `Major`, `Minor`, etc.

[See this issue for more](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2243).
[See code running here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KvQPm2).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I tried to find the old code that did not throw at https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commits/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/VersionConverter.cs but I cannot see how it worked.

Comment: The old code is just the default JSON (de)serializer I think -- it didn't do anything special for `Version`, it just serialized its properties, and deserialized by using reflection to write to its private fields. The breaking change was to add `VersionConverter`